# How to make Xcode templates connvert ___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER___ to uppercase

Tags: xcode, templates, uppercase, lowercase

Quick question description.
There is C header file template which has this code as a template:

```
#ifndef ___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER_______FILEEXTENSION___
#define ___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER_______FILEEXTENSION___

#endif
```

Logically it produces the next code when file "SomeHeader" is created:

```
#ifndef SomeHeader_h
#define SomeHeader_h

#endif
```

The task is to have those defines in uppercase form, like this:

```
#ifndef SOMEHEADER_H
#define SOMEHEADER_H

#endif
```

The question is - is there a way to do this? Maybe there is some special function to operate on placeholders? Is it possible at all?

Comment: I need the same thing, but lowercase! :)

Comment: But it looks like we both won't see it happen, apparently not with current XCode.

Comment: Yup, I came to the same conclusion after reading other articles and such. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, unfortunately. It was no critical issue anyway.